# How to get meaningful results of kmeans in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

I have a dataset which looks like this:

> {'dns_query_count': '11', 'http_hostnames_count': '7', 'dest_port_count': '3', 'ip_count': '11', 'signature_count': '0', 'src_ip': '10.0.64.42', 'http_user_agent_count': '2'}

This is already converted to dict from csv

Then i use DictVectorizer to convert it

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
vec = DictVectorizer()
d = vec.fit_transform(data).toarray()
```

Then i try to use Kmeans on it

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
k = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(d)
```

My question is how do i get infromation about which row of my data belongs to what cluster?

I expect to get something like this:

> {'dns_query_count': '11', 'http_hostnames_count': '7', 'dest_port_count': '3', 'ip_count': '11', 'signature_count': '0', 'src_ip': '10.0.64.42', 'http_user_agent_count': '2', cluster: '1'}

Can someone give me an step by step example how to go from raw data like i showed to the same data with information to which clusters they belong?

For example i used Weka for this dataset and it showed me what i want - i can click datapoints on the graphs and read exactly which datapoints belongs to which cluster. How to get similar results with sklearn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will show how you can retrieve the cluster id for each row and the cluster centers. I have also measured the distance from each row to each centroid so you can see that the rows are properly assigned to the clusters.

```
In [1]:

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from numpy.random import random
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean

# I'm going to generate some random data so you can just copy this and see it work

random_data = []

for i in range(0,10):
    random_data.append({'dns_query_count': random(),
 'http_hostnames_count': random(),
 'dest_port_count': random(),
 'ip_count': random(),
 'signature_count': random(),
 'src_ip': random(),
 'http_user_agent_count': random()}
)

df = pd.DataFrame(random_data)

km = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(df)

df['cluster_id'] = km.labels_

# get the cluster centers and compute the distance from each point to the center
# this will show that all points are assigned to the correct cluster

def distance_to_centroid(row, centroid):
    row = row[['dns_query_count',
                'http_hostnames_count',
                'dest_port_count',
                'ip_count',
                'signature_count',
                'src_ip',
                'http_user_agent_count']]
    return euclidean(row, centroid)

# to get the cluster centers use km.cluster_centers_

df['distance_to_center0'] = df.apply(lambda r: distance_to_centroid(r,
    km.cluster_centers_[0]),1)

df['distance_to_center1'] = df.apply(lambda r: distance_to_centroid(r,
    km.cluster_centers_[1]),1)

df.head()

Out [1]:
   dest_port_count  dns_query_count  http_hostnames_count  \
0         0.516920         0.135925              0.090209   
1         0.528907         0.898578              0.752862   
2         0.426108         0.604251              0.524905   
3         0.373985         0.606492              0.503487   
4         0.319943         0.970707              0.707207   

   http_user_agent_count  ip_count  signature_count    src_ip  cluster_id  \
0               0.987878  0.808556         0.860859  0.642014           0   
1               0.417033  0.130365         0.067021  0.322509           1   
2               0.528679  0.216118         0.041491  0.522445           1   
3               0.780292  0.130404         0.048353  0.911599           1   
4               0.156117  0.719902         0.484865  0.752840           1   

   distance_to_center0  distance_to_center1  
0             0.846099             1.124509  
1             1.175765             0.760310  
2             0.970046             0.615725  
3             1.054555             0.946233  
4             0.640906             1.020849
```

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans.fit_predict

Comment: I already tried that - i just got a matrix with bunch of 1 and 0. I mean how do i use that with original data?

Comment: I'll add some more code to my example, that will tie everything together

Comment: Thanks. Now it's more clear. But i've got another problem now - i got almost  50/50 split which is clearly is incorrect. Weka however shows correct results with 80/20 split with obvious outliers. Why is that? I use Simple k-means in Weka.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with weka to tell you what it's doing different. You could try normalizing your data, you might be getting inconsistent results due to the scale of your variables.
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html

Comment: I've tried with preprocessing.scale and set fixed random value for Kmeans so results won't change every time. Now it's look more accurate with 71/28 split. But what is weird is that results is mostly wrong. Outlier data points which belongs to smaller cluster get into big one for some reason and normal data points into smaller one. Why it's behave like that?

Comment: Also, are you sure that resulting matrix from Kmeans run is not shuffled? Like can i be sure that first row in my dataframe linked to first item in kmeans predict matrix?

Comment: I am sure that the results are not shuffled and I'm also sure that the results are not wrong in the sense that each row is assigned to the cluster that it is closest to. I edited my response to help show this. If you are concerned with outliers being assigned to the wrong group, you could try DBSCAN. Instead of assigning outliers to groups it will simply leave them unclassified.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. But i'm going to given up on scikit for now - i played with it for the last two days and it is way too inconsistent and requires way too much work. I couldn't figure out a lot of nuances like do i need to normalize and scale or i do not, what random state is need etc. I get back to it after i dig deeper into ML, for simple prototyping i will stay with Weka.